# iOS UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I am trying to make the spacing between my cells = 5

In the iPhone 4s the UICollectionViewCell becomes a square but I need rectangle.

I need iPhone4s iPhone5 iPhone6 iPhone 6Plus the cell, but the width and height of the cell is always wrong. I don't know how to do it automatically.

This is my code:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 20) /2, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height) /3);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please pay more attention to your spelling and grammar. Questions that are hard to understand don't get answers. I tried fixing it, but I am not certain I understand what you want. So please go over it again and fix your grammar.

Comment: Looks like you haven't referenced to documentation, nor to google. Try searching, please. This question was asked a lot of times. Besides, there're a lot of guides on creating CollectionViews. Your case is nothing special to create new question

Comment: Thank you, I have solved this problem, my English is not very good, all the expression is not very clear, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some change in your code will works fine

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
int itemWidth=([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 20)/2;
int intemHeight=itemWidth*2/3;
    return CGSizeMake(itemWidth, intemHeight);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have solved this problem, thank you for your help.